# C for loop 1-100 odd number and sum all the values but it gave the wrong values

Tags: c, loops, math

```
int main (){
    int i, total;
        printf("Loop to one hundred.\n");
        for(i=1; i<=100; i+=2){
            printf("%d  ",i);
            total += i;
        }
   printf("\nTotal: %d", total);
   return 0;
}
```

[image]
So I have a C programming code up on it, and I have the result as well. But what I found is the result isn't what the answer that I want. I was expecting the result is 2500 but it gave 2516.

Can someone point it out what's wrong on my code?

> If someone suggest using while loop, yes while loop can gave me the correct answer which is 2500 but I want to know why I use for loop it gave me 2516.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You forgot to initialize the variable `total` before starting additions.

```
    int i, total;
```

should be

```
    int i, total = 0;
```

Comment: I see, but how about the extra values 16 added on my total? Do you have any idea?

Comment: Using values of unintialized automatic variable invokes *undefined behavior*. You got 16 by chance.